# Phase change into Bose-Einstein Condensate

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

I am a high school chemistry/physics teacher and I was just wondering what the phase change into/out of a Bose-Einstein Condensate is called?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that it is common enough to have a name such as 'melting'. But I'm open to correction by a BEC physicist...

Answer (score 1):

The phase change is simply called "Bose condensation" or "Bose-Einstein condensation"

https://www.nature.com/articles/416211a
https://www.nist.gov/publications/bose-condensation-photons-thermalized-laser-cooling-atoms

Comment: Thanks!  Does it transition back to a solid?  Is there a name for that change?  Thanks!

Comment: Atoms in solids do not undergo Bose-condensation, usually it is a gas/vapor to Bose-Einstein condensate transition. In solids the analogous transition is the superfluid/superconducting transition. In both cases, you would usually call the reverse process simply "melting".

Comment: It should be noted that a BEC is just a metastable state, the true ground state is indeed a solid. BEC atoms do form molecules via three-body recombinations, i.e. solids. To make and keep a BEC, you slow these processes down by using dilute (low density) gases.